# Google Play services location APIs как реализовать по-умному, по-профессиональному?

Tags: геолокация, android, java, google-maps-api-2

Хочется открыть приложение, и чтоб оно быстро определило местоположение (с точностью до подъезда), показало его на карте, без лишних дерганий карты и остановило обновления, так же красиво, как в популярных приложениях (например, поиска такси).

Нужны достойные примеры реализации.

И может, кто-нибудь поможет с грамотными настройками для этих нужд (исходя из своего опыта).

Пока я использую эти:

```
private static final long INTERVAL = 10000;
private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = INTERVAL / 2;
private static final long REMOVE_UPDATE = 60000;//Останавливает фуседлокетион аодейт по расписанию после запуска.
private static final long REFRESH_TIME = REMOVE_UPDATE / 2;// время после которого last координаты считаются старыми и запускается новый апдейт фузедлокетион
private static final float MINIMUM_ACCURACY = 50.0f;
```

Comment: Очень обширный вопрос. Попробуйте конкретнее задать.